# Is it possible to send a message not to all observers using .net Rx?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, observer-pattern

I have a situation where there is an observable and let's say 10 observers attached to it. I would like to send the message to each new observer only until an observer somehow says to observable that it recognizes the message and it will process it. At this moment I would like to stop sending this message to other observers.

In other words each observer knows how to process a particular type of message and each one will take and process the message it recognizes. Others don't need to receive it after the one that recognizes it started processing. How this situation could be implemented with the reactive extensions? I assume we need some sort of notification back to the observable but I don't see how can it be done.

Comment: This sounds more like some [chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) problem rather than Rx.  I don't think you're going to get any bi-directional communication with Rx - the best you can do is filter the sequence before subscribing an observer.  Some specific code might be useful here.

Comment: Indeed this is not really an Rx problem.  You can either subscribe a single "controller" observable that keeps a list of candidates and whenever an item arrives, the controller tries the candidates one by one until one accepts the item.  Or each observer can "attach" itself to the chain using `.Where()` and it would return `false` when it "claimed" the item.

Comment: I would agree it is a chain of responsibility on top of the observable. I simply hoped that there is a quick solution in the Rx.

Comment: @alex.49.98 - You're not thinking in the Rx way. You're thinking in an object oriented way. Rx is functional. You do this kind of thing by adding `.Where(...)` clauses to the observable to filter your messages.

Comment: I understand that I can filter messages with .Where(..). I'm thinking in a way to optimize the code. The message identification part takes certain time. I definitely don't need to repeat it if an observer for particular message is found. Basically it seems almost like that. I have to put my selection code into .Where(...) or .Select(...) and then call custom observers in a loop using a method signature like bool OnNext(T value). Each observer will check if the message is its and return true or false. The loop will stop as soon as an observer returns true.

Comment: By the way, I see there is this interface in the Rx public interface IObserver<in TValue, out TResult>. Potentially it should be able to return bool from OnNext call which probably could be used in my situation by I didn't find any usage of this interface. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with. Any comments, ideas, suggestions and critics is very welcome. The most interesting part is that `IObserver<TValue, TResult>` public interface already exists in the Rx library but it's used only in the Notification object. What I did, I created `IObservable<TValue, TResult>` counterpart, SelectiveSubject to take care of the logic to call observers until one of them returns true and ToSelective method extension. I'm actually surprised that it was not done in the library, at least the `IObservable<TValue, TResult>` part. After all, `IObserver<TValue, TResult>` existed.

```
public interface IObservable<out TValue, in TResult> {
   IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<TValue, TResult> objObserver);
}



internal class SelectiveSubject<T> : IObserver<T>, IObservable<T, bool> {
   private readonly LinkedList<IObserver<T, bool>> _ObserverList;

   public SelectiveSubject() {
      _ObserverList = new LinkedList<IObserver<T, bool>>();
   }

   public void OnNext(T value) {
      lock(_ObserverList) {
         foreach(IObserver<T, bool> objObserver in _ObserverList) {
            if(objObserver.OnNext(value)) {
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void OnError(Exception exception) {
      lock(_ObserverList) {
         foreach(IObserver<T, bool> objObserver in _ObserverList) {
            if(objObserver.OnError(exception)) {
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public void OnCompleted() {
      lock(_ObserverList) {
         foreach(IObserver<T, bool> objObserver in _ObserverList) {
            if(objObserver.OnCompleted()) {
               break;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T, bool> objObserver) {
      LinkedListNode<IObserver<T, bool>> objNode;
      lock(_ObserverList) {
         objNode = _ObserverList.AddLast(objObserver);
      }
      return Disposable.Create(() => {
         lock(objNode.List) {
            objNode.List.Remove(objNode);
         }
      });
   }
}



public static IObservable<T, bool> ToSelective<T>(this IObservable<T> objThis) {
   var objSelective = new SelectiveSubject<T>();
   objThis.Subscribe(objSelective);
   return objSelective;
}
```

Now the usage is as simple as this

```
 IConnectableObservable<int> objGenerator = Observable.Generate(0, i => i < 100, i => i + 1, i => i).Publish();
 IObservable<int, bool> objSelective = objGenerator.ToSelective();

 var objDisposableList = new CompositeDisposable(2) {
    objSelective.Subscribe(i => {
       Console.Write("1");
       if(i % 2 == 0) {
          Console.Write("!");
          return true;
       }
       else {
          Console.Write(".");
          return false;
       }
    }),
    objSelective.Subscribe(i => {
       Console.Write("2");
       Console.Write("!");
       return true;
    })
 };

 objGenerator.Connect();
 objDisposableList.Dispose();
```

In the example the first subscriber takes care of every other value in the sequence and the second subscriber takes care of the rest.